# NHibernate delete sql null check issue

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When I call " task.Assignee.Clear() " nhibernate create below sql for SQLLite and SQLServer (one record in Assignee at call time)

```
DELETE FROM TaskAssignees
WHERE  TaskId = 'd8e13c83-20b8-4ce6-a814-a264000c21a6' /* @p0 */
       AND UserId = 'f676b54b-d986-4659-a4aa-9103d928f91b' /* @p1 */
       AND TeamId = NULL /* @p2 */
       AND DepartmentId = NULL /* @p3 */
       AND VirtualUserId = NULL /* @p4 */
       AND IsMain = 1
```

This query not performed because = NULL is wrong check for sql, must be like this

```
DELETE FROM TaskAssignees
WHERE  TaskId = 'd8e13c83-20b8-4ce6-a814-a264000c21a6' /* @p0 */
       AND UserId = 'f676b54b-d986-4659-a4aa-9103d928f91b' /* @p1 */
       AND TeamId is NULL /* @p2 */
       AND DepartmentId is  NULL /* @p3 */
       AND VirtualUserId is  NULL /* @p4 */
       AND IsMain = 1
```

How can I fix this issuee?

I use FluentNhibernate for mapping, and NHibernate 3.3

Mapping and class:

```
public TaskMap()
{
    Table("Tasks");
    CompositeId<TaskId>(x => x.Id).KeyProperty(t => t.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();

    HasMany(x => x.Assignees)
        .AsList(c => c.Column("AssigneeIndex"))
        .Component(m =>
        {
            m.Component(x => x.UserId, mm => mm.Map(x => x.Id).Column("UserId").Nullable());
            m.Component(x => x.TeamId, mm => mm.Map(x => x.Id).Column("TeamId").Nullable());
            m.Component(x => x.DepartmentId, mm => mm.Map(x => x.Id).Column("DepartmentId").Nullable());
            m.Component(x => x.VirtualUserId, mm => mm.Map(x => x.Id).Column("VirtualUserId").Nullable());
            m.Map(x => x.IsMain).Not.Nullable();
        })
        .KeyColumn("TaskId")
        .Table("TaskAssignees")
        .Cascade.All();
}

public class Task : Entity<TaskId> 
{
    public TaskId Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<TaskAssignee> Assignees {get;set;}
}

public class TaskAssignee : ValueObject
{
    public UserId UserId {get;protected set;}
    public TeamId TeamId {get;protected set;}
    public VirtualUserId VirtualUserId {get;protected set;}
    public DepartmentId DepartmentId {get;protected set;}
    public bool IsMain {get;protected set;}
}

public class TaskId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Id {get;protected set;}
}

public class TeamId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Id {get;protected set;}
}

public class VirtualUserId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Id {get;protected set;}
}

public class DepartmentId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Id {get;protected set;}
}

public class UserId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Id {get;protected set;}
}
```

Comment: You need to show your mappings and involved classes - there is no way currently to understand what all those columns are or why NHibernate behaves this way.

Comment: And the dialect you are using.. are you changing your dialect for the different databases?

Comment: I found this: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-incollections

"Please note that a composite element mapping doesn't support null-able properties if you're using a <set>. NHibernate has to use each columns value to identify a record when deleting objects (there is no separate primary key column in the composite element table), which is not possible with null values. You have to either use only not-null properties in a composite-element or choose a <list>, <map>, <bag> or <idbag>."

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you are using a `set`, and hit [this documented limitation](http://nhibernate.info/previous-doc/v5.0/ref/components.html#components-incollections) (as [pointed](/questions/19612354/nhibernate-delete-sql-null-check-issue#comment29147765_19612354) by @oguzh4n):

> Please note that a composite element mapping doesn't support null-able
>   properties if you're using a `<set>`. NHibernate has to use each columns
>   value to identify a record when deleting objects (there is no separate
>   primary key column in the composite element table), which is not
>   possible with null values. You have to either use only not-null
>   properties in a composite-element or choose a `<list>`, `<map>`, `<bag>` or
>   `<idbag>`.

This limitation will be removed in NHibernate 5.2, which should be available in Q3 2018.